# I'm trying to connect MySQl and Flask but I keep getting an error. I'm using XAMPP for this web app

Tags: mysql, flask, visual-c++, xampp

So, I'm trying to connect my sql database on xampp to my flask database.

I'm using this command:

```
pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

but I keep getting an error and it tells me to download Microsoft Visual C++.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I tried it again after I downloaded the app but it's not working at all. It still shows up with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go to

```
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Where you can find  at the bottom

[image]

under
`all downloads  --> Too for visual  Studio 2019`
You find

```
Buildtools für Visual Studio 2019
```

After installing the installer you must choose `Desktop Delevelopment with c++`

After that the message disappears

Comment: i added a picture it is in german, microssft doesn't let me choose english but you get where to find eelse use the search function from  mcriosft

Comment: which one do you get? But you should accept this one and ask another, if you can't find a solution